# Post-build script and "at" operator

Tags: windows, visual-studio, build

Having some `post-bulid` script for `Visual C++` there is a line like below:

```
SET destination=d:\GAMES\Fallout2\@RP\ddraw.dll
```

What is the purpose of the "at" ("@") symbol before "RP" in the `destination` path definition? What is suppose to do here? It rather NOT to be the "be less verbose" operator in this context.